# Tooltip not working on second line in NVD3 MultiChart

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I have a `multiChart` in `angular-nvd3`, which should display sales count and total income for each day.

`<nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>`

And here's the options and data:

```
$scope.options = {
    chart: {
        type: 'multiChart',
        height: 450,
        margin : {
            top: 30,
            right: 90,
            bottom: 50,
            left: 70
        },
        color: d3.scale.category10().range(),
        useInteractiveGuideline: true,
        xAxis: {
            axisLabel: "Day",
            tickFormat: function(d){
                return d3.time.format('%b %d')(new Date(d));;
            }
        },
        yAxis1: {
            axisLabel: "Orders",
            tickFormat: d3.format('d')
        },
        yAxis2: {
            axisLabel: "Income (Lari)",
            tickFormat: function(d){
                return Math.round(d / 100) + " GEL";
            }
        }
    }
};
$scope.data = [{
    yAxis: 2,
    type: 'line',
    key: "Income",
    values: data.map(function (item) {
        return {
            series: 0,
            x: new Date(item._id.year, item._id.month, item._id.day),
            y: item.total
        };
    })
},
{
    yAxis: 1,
    key: "Orders",
    type: 'line',
    values: data.map(function (item) {
        return {
            series: 1,
            x: new Date(item._id.year, item._id.month, item._id.day),
            y: item.count
        };
    })
}];
```

Data item before transforming:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "year": 2015,
    "month": 11,
    "day": 26
  },
  "total": 1078,
  "count": 1
},
```

Hovering the first line shows tooltip, displaying the Y value, but the second line is completely ignored on mouseover. Disabling the first line shows following error in console:

```
d3.js:5948 Error: Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="translate(NaN,NaN)"
d3.transform @ d3.js:5948d3
interpolateTransform @ d3.js:6049
(anonymous function) @ d3.js:8754
(anonymous function) @ d3.js:8945
d3_class.forEach @ d3.js:341
start @ d3.js:8944
schedule @ d3.js:8912
d3_timer_mark @ d3.js:2165
d3_timer_step @ d3.js:2146
```

And causes the window to overflow horizontally, which is because tooltip is shown with a huge offset. Can be observed when zooming out extremely.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to reproduce your issue exactly in a plunker, but I took your example data object and created a couple additional datapoints in a [plunker of my own](http://plnkr.co/edit/hu9gYAJG0KaMi9CTjbz1?p=preview). The tooltip functionality is working fine in this plunker, and I think it must have to do with how you are mapping the values into the `$scope.data` object.

I took the approach of creating an external function to build the values into the `$scope.data` array:

```
function mapValues(src, dest, series, key) {
    dest[series].values = src.map(function(item) {
        return {
            series: series,
            x: new Date(item._id.year, item._id.month, item._id.day),
            y: item[key]
        };
    })
}
```

And then called the function with the parameters you specified:

```
$scope.data = [{
    yAxis: 2,
    type: 'line',
    key: "Income"
},
{
    yAxis: 1,
    key: "Orders",
    type: 'line'
}];

mapValues(json, $scope.data, 0, 'total');
mapValues(json, $scope.data, 1, 'count');
```

Anyway, may be too late to help you now, but just thought I'd offer this way of creating your data object to someone else who might run into this issue.